# axios: как получить только заголовки?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Есть код:

```
const response = await axios.get(link)
console.log(response.status)
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то получить статус без получения `response.data`? Т.е., мне нужны только заголовки, без контента страницы, чтобы сократить время и ресурсы.

Если это нельзя сделать через axios, есть ли другие варианты?

Comment: axios.head подойдет?

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы сам сервер вам возвращал только заголовки, без данных? Тогда вам нужна модификация сервера. Axios и подобные библиотеки лишь отправляют http запрос и парсят ответ.

Comment: Anatoly спасибо! то что нужно